Does hawking radiation leak information in a time-independent way, and could it carry charge as well as being thermal? Is this how we model it?
I’ve been working on a series of quantum circuit experiments to explore information preservation in Hawking radiation, focusing on whether injected properties like charge and spin are encoded in the emitted radiation. My goal is to simulate a black hole's behavior in an idealized setting and analyze how quantum information evolves in the process. I’d appreciate feedback on the methodology, the results, and how closely this aligns with established theories. This is not for school, I just need to know so I can move forward. All the code is linked on my github if you want to see the results for yourself, or so someone can tell me if I did something wrong in what/how I found something or the methodology. If Im not using the right word for something, please correct me but be patient, I really do want to learn but what I found I think is quite weird. Sorry if I do not ask the question in a way or phrase this post in a way that seems off-topic, irrelevant, informal, or asks you to review code. I want to learn and thats what im here for. People on physics se told me to put it here, or coding se was inappropriate for this.
I do want to test for spin, maybe how the black hole stores the mass. I think if charge can be preserved then maybe something like color can too since the 3 forces unify though I dont want to speculate too much. This builds on the holographic principle. I also tested what negative energy does in ex5 but it seems to indicate negative energy influences radiation states as well. More work needs to be done.
Simulating a Black Hole In my experiments, I model the black hole and radiation system as follows:
Black Hole as a Qubit:
A single qubit represents the black hole’s quantum state, capturing the fundamental idea that black holes have a finite set of quantum properties (mass, charge, spin) encoded in their event horizon, in addition you can view this system as the Hawking radiation particle pairs split, they are entangled because of conservation laws. I also try color charge but the results have been confusing, which is what I mostly need help w.
Radiation as Qubits:
Additional qubits represent the emitted Hawking radiation, which entangle with the black hole qubit as the system evolves.
Evaporation Process:
Radiation qubits are sequentially entangled with the black hole qubit to mimic the emission of Hawking radiation over time.
Charge Injection:
I simulate charge injections into the black hole using Pauli gates (X for positive charge, Z for negative charge) to analyze whether these properties are encoded in the radiation.
Limitations of the Simulation While the quantum circuit captures certain aspects of black hole physics, there are critical limitations:
No Spatial Geometry:
The simulation does not account for the curved spacetime geometry near a black hole, which plays a significant role in Hawking radiation.
Information Encoding Simplified:
The black hole qubit directly interacts with the radiation qubits, but the real-world mechanism for encoding information in Hawking radiation remains an open question.
No Event Horizon Constraints:
In reality, the event horizon prevents signals from escaping a black hole. This simulation treats the black hole as a quantum system without such spatial constraints.
Idealized Dynamics:
The system assumes perfect unitary evolution and ignores potential complications from decoherence or quantum gravity effects. Despite these simplifications, the model aims to test whether key principles—such as information preservation and entanglement—can be explored in a controlled, quantum mechanical context.
Experimental Goals The primary questions driving this work are:
Information Encoding: Does the radiation qubits’ state reflect the black hole’s quantum properties, such as injected charge or spin?
Static vs. Dynamic Behavior: Does the black hole encode information globally in a time-independent manner (static encoding), or does the radiation evolve dynamically based on the timing of interactions?
Insights into the Information Paradox: Can the results offer new insights into how black holes preserve information, consistent with unitarity?
Methodology Here’s an overview of how the experiments are set up:
System Initialization:
The black hole qubit is initialized in a superposition state, entangled with radiation qubits via controlled gates (CX).
Charge Injections:
I alternate between injecting positive (X gate) and negative (Z gate) charges into the black hole qubit, testing how these affect the radiation’s quantum state.
Evaporation Simulation:
Radiation qubits are sequentially entangled with the black hole qubit to mimic the gradual release of Hawking radiation.
Measurements:
Radiation qubits are measured to analyze how information is encoded. Entanglement entropy and statevector evolution are tracked to study the distribution of information.
Results
Experiment A: Static Behavior Measurement: The radiation collapsed into a single dominant state (0000) with 100% probability.
Implication: This suggests limited entanglement or static encoding, where the radiation doesn’t reflect dynamic changes in the black hole’s state.
Experiment B: Dynamic Behavior Measurement: Outcomes showed a diverse distribution (0000, 0101, 1111, 1010) with nearly equal probabilities.
Implication: This suggests time-dependent encoding, where radiation qubits retain memory of past charge injections.
Charge Preservation
Across all experiments, the emitted radiation consistently encoded injected charge states, supporting the hypothesis that information is preserved.
Questions for the Community
How well does this simulation capture key aspects of black hole physics?
Are the idealizations (e.g., no spatial geometry or event horizon) reasonable for exploring information preservation? Does the methodology align with theoretical models?
Are there improvements I could make to better simulate the entanglement and evaporation process? Static vs. Dynamic Encoding:
Do the results suggest new insights into whether information release is time-dependent or global?
Implications for the Information Paradox:
Can these findings contribute to understanding how black holes preserve information, or do they merely confirm existing assumptions?
Code https://github.com/NiloGregginz33/QMGRExperiments Closing Notes I’ve done my best to set up this simulation based on theoretical insights, but I’m not a physicist by training.
I’d love feedback on:
Whether the methodology and results align with established physics, or if any of these experiments have been done before this on this topic. Any suggestions for refining the model or testing additional scenarios.
One Question I would have to ask would be...
Does the methodology work for modeling the rest of the questions I have from the title and can I start to draw conclusions on preservation of the green color charge based on what the experiment on EM charge and color charges say?
Thank you for reading, and I appreciate any insights you can offer!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Added a clear question or attempted to under the one question i would have to ask thing

I do not pretend this is answer, rather long comment and some ideas for you.
Your question is still really wide as you are asking to validate your theory/methodology.
Please have a look at these articles dealing with relationship of quantum computing and holographic principle: first and second.
Although the articles are rather popular, they contain links to papers published in Nature.
Also note that above mentioned works deal with wormhole rather than black holes. However, they cover relationship of quantum mechanics and general relativity, so still may be useful.
You can also contact authors of the articles as they seems to be experts in a field you are asking about.
Hope this helps, at least a little.

You are so accurate because I literally heard about that article and then was trying to replicate it but introduce charge (and now way more) instead of keeping it at spin bc Hawking radiation should only be thermal right

@ManavNaik: Sorry, I am not really expert at black holes etc. I am afraid I cannot help more....

Why does no one want to help me I feel like people just keep making up reasons like it was the off topic thing and it’s never specific enough and then “oh we can’t help you with homework” even when I said I’m doing independently first.

my focus here is on whether my quantum circuit correctly handles:
Superposition
Entanglement
Charge Injection
Are the gates and sequence I’ve used appropriate for achieving the desired entanglement and charge conservation?
I understand that this isn’t strictly about black holes but rather a quantum computing implementation to test information encoding. Any insights or improvements on the circuit would be very helpful. @Martin-Vesely

@ManavNaik: I do want you to feel uncomfortable, I tried to help you as I can with my answer. You said that you know about these articles, which I could not have known. I also told that I am not expert on topic you are asking about, actually my field is finance and computer science, theory of relativity is just my hobby.  So, I cannot help more. Maybe someone else. As I mentioned, try to contact authors of the articles on simulation of wormholes on Sycamore QPU. It seems they are the most appropriate to help you.

i am even more unqualified to talk about this bc I havent gotten through my computer science degree bachelors, thats why I just need people to tell me if im doing everything properly. I also really really just wanna show people, since what I found doing this is so weird as well as you know make sure im not a crazy person. Ive learned about relativity as a hobby as well, even heard of Hawking Radiation. Even though I stick to PBS Space Time on YT though, what im seeing is inconsistent to what I saw on the show, but since its not my degree i cant rly ask professors

Let me be clear, its correct about the theoretical stuff, but this observation matched every theory. It just did a little something extra that was violationg another symmetry, Leonard Susskind seems on track
